# axios post is not working but same url is working with fetch api

Tags: react-native, axios

I am making a post request with axios in react native, it is working normally except in this file, to test I replaced it with fetch api and it worked fine.

The second line in my code executes fine and the first (with axios) doesn't, I commented it the first line and the third one which prints result from first one then it works, if I uncomment it nothing get printed (the first line stops the next lines)

I am sure axios imported and working because I have get requests working in same file.

```
//let response = await axios.post("http://testing.api.okatruck.com/api/customers/requestTripC",{})
let response2 = await fetch("http://testing.api.okatruck.com/api/customers/requestTripC",{method: 'POST'})
//console.log(response)
console.log(response2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```js
const url = "http://testing.api.okatruck.com/api/customers/requestTripC";
const headers = {headers: { 
"Authorization": `Token ${token}`, //edit this line according to the backend authorization
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}};
const body = {};
axios
.post(url, body, headers)
.then(res => {
  console.log("request received",res);
})
.catch(err => console.log("TODO: Handle error axios", err));
```

Comment: TODO: Handle error axios [Error: Request failed with status code 401]
At least it printed something, what is the difference here?

Comment: Can I know if your response2 shows some data? and do you have some kind of token for accessing the data?

Comment: response2 return 401, which is normal because I need to send a token with headers plus my data